# Access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.name" "read") Java Applet for 1.8.0_25 version

Tags: java, jar, applet, user-permissions, jarsigner

I have this applet:

```
import java.applet.Applet;

public class UserNapplet extends Applet {
public void init() { }
public String getUser() {
    try {
    return System.getProperty("user.name");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "error";
    }
}
}
```

and html tag:

```
<div id="aple"><applet code="UserNapplet.class" height="0" width="0" id="uname" archive="UserNapplet.jar"/></div>`
```

How to make it work?

What I did?
a bat file .....

```
del UserNapplet.jar
del UserNapplet.class
javac UserNapplet.java
jar cvf UserNapplet.jar UserNapplet.class
jar ufm UserNapplet.jar mymanifest.txt
jarsigner -verbose UserNapplet.jar SecGen
```

//(SecGen is my "certificate")...

mymanifest.txt says:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Name: SecGen
Codebase: http://172.31.31.4/MyAppDir `  (a folder in C.\inetpub\wwwroot)
```

The running policytools generates

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Wed Dec 10 08:29:52 PYST 2014*/    
/* DO NOT EDIT */    
grant codeBase "file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyAppDir/UserNapplet.jar" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read";
};
```

With all of this.... the applet still throwing

```
java.security.accesscontrolexception: access denied ("java.util.propertypermission" "user.name" "read")
```

What more to do?

Comment: Digitally sign the code.  I'm surprised you did not see that suggestion in your research.

Comment: BTW - Code formatting for blocks of text - to do that properly, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: I am trying digitally sign the code, but with autosign, because this isn't an internet application, it's an intranet one

Comment: the code is formatted with that tool, don´t see?

Comment: Did you use a trusted certificate (or imported your self signed into your Browser truststore).

Comment: I generated a certificate from server and imported on each client web navigator (mozilla firefox, chrome and IE). I added the server domain in exception list from control panel of Java security tab, IP and name (the certificate was generated with name: ex.: admin.domain.local, then I put https://admin.domain.local/MyAppDir/ and the application launchs... but the error persists. I am logged with the admin account too for reduce posibilities... but... anything...

Comment: This case is resolved. Adding a privileged instruction, it runs. Show the applet caution window, but... it's nothing...

 private String getUser() {
  try {
    String user = AccessController.doPrivileged(
           new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
             public String run() {
               return System.getProperty("user.name");
               }
              });
    return user; 
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return "nácore";
  }
 }
}